# Average Island Scale for multiple oblects in a scene

Tags: materials, uv, texture-baking

I want to fabricate my blender file by printing out their UV maps on card stock and fold them together.

'Average Island Scale' works on the same UV set.
But I have many objects in my scene and I want all their UV’s to be proportional to how they are in Blender world space.

Any ideas?
Thanks

~be

Comment: Can you join them? If you want to be neat, you can seperate them afterwards, take the original objects and copy the new object's UVs to the old objects. Tedious though.

Comment: Thanks @FrederikSteinmetz
Do you mean creating a new, big UV map for All the objects using Average Isle Scale and then bake to texture?

Comment: That would be best practice. However it would be easier (and saving you from creating a huge canvas) to select each object's vertices and unwrap them seperately with overlapping uvs. Then either work with multiple materials, or split them back